# Return page from inline edit on standard page when View action is overridden

Tags: inline, detail-page, page-override, nooverride

We have a custom object which has the View action overridden with a custom VF page.  This override lets us go directly to the custom VF page from lists and other links within the CRM.  Some users still need to use the standard detail page to edit values, so we have a link on the custom VF page to go back to the detail page (using the parameter `nooverride=1`).

The problem now is that whenever they edit from the detail page, they are returned to the custom VF page, and not the detail page.  This is a jarring experience, especially for inline edits.

I was able to add the `saveURL` param to return them back to the detail page after they save on the edit page, but inline edits seem to return the after save URL in the AJAX response.  How can I make the inline save action return back to the detail page and/or use the `nooverride` param?

Comment: did you try using retUrl parameter?

Comment: I did, but it seems to have no effect.